# ElasticSearch Malform Qquery

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm getting **"[must] query malformed, no start_object after query name"** when I do the following aggregation query in ElasticSearch 5.5. Any idea?

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/car/car/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": { "match": { "car_color": "Yellow" }  }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
      "all_cars": {
         "global": {},
         "aggregations": {
            "car_makes": {
               "filter": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "terms": {"car_color": ["Yellow"]}
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "aggregations": {
                  "filtered_car_make": {
                     "terms": {"field": "car_make"}
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the match query not inside a bool query?

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": { "car_color": "Yellow" }
   },
   "aggregations": {
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your aggregation filter

```
           "filter": {
              "must": [
                 {
                    "terms": {"car_color": ["Yellow"]}
                 }
              ]
           },
```

Needs to be fixed like this:

```
           "filter": {
               "terms": {"car_color": ["Yellow"]}
           },
```